# LVDS (LCD data) cable replacement

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, display

The video on my mid-2009 13" Macbook Pro freezes and becomes noisy sometimes, depending on the position of the lid, pressure, etc.

I opened it, and could reproduce the behavior by poking at the LVDS (LCD data) cable.

Is replacing the cable something the Genius Bar can do quickly, or am I better off doing it myself? The cable costs $20 online. I watched the YouTube videos showing how to remove the LCD -- I think I could do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a very difficult think to do, I used to work at the Genius bar and I can confirm that it takes roughly about 20 mins for me to do, but there's always a queue of repairs to be done so it's very unlikely they will get it done there and then for you, unless you get a nice Genius. 
If I were you and if the computer is out of warranty, then I'd say to do it yourself.

Comment: are the instructions for DYI

Answer (score 1):

Ask for a price at the genius bar, I'm assuming the price will be rather high (official repair centers in Austria charge a lot more than 20$ for the cable and add about an hour of work - the whole process would probably cost almost as much as the MacBook is worth)